# Laravel updateOrCreate with composite key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table that's defined thus:

```
 Schema::create('tableA', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('label_id')->unsigned();
            $table->date('date');
            $table->integer('value');
            $table->unique(['user_id','label_id','date']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The table uses a composite key of user_id, label_id and date.

I would like to update the table using the Model::updateOrCreate method thus:

```
 Model::updateOrCreate(
                [
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'label_id' => $label_id,
                    'date' => $date,
                    'value' => $value,
                ]);
```

But I get an error if I run the method when a row with the composite key already exists because it seems Laravel doesn't work with composite keys.

For example row

```
[
user_id:2,
label_id:3,
date:'2019-04-04',
value: 44
]
```

cannot be updated using

```
Model::updateOrCreate([
    user_id:2,
    label_id:3,
    date:'2019-04-04',
    value: 100
]);
```

Does this mean there's no way to use updateOrCreate and I need to check each row if it exists before I attempt to add it ?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.6.34

Comment: I think the bigger issue here is that you are trying to use a pivot as a normal model.

Comment: @apokryfos .. what is your basis for calling his 'update' example a "pivot"? The OP is not processing an "intermediate table" (as Laravel describes a pivot) -- he's simply trying to update a row which happens to have a composite key. Many of us who've designed data for 20+ years **will** use composite keys, as they make more sense & are more clear to us than some random meaningless "id" field. So why are you describing it as a 'pivot'? I think the accepted answer addresses the OP's question quite nicely.

Comment: @McAuley I'm describing it as a pivot because the composite key seems to be comprised of foreign keys. I may be wrong about this since it's not explicitly specified, but the naming convention does seem to imply that. If this is the case then this table will not make any sense outside of the context of describing a relationship and that is what I mean when I say it is a pivot table. I only mention this because Laravel has tools to work with pivot tables through the entities that participate in the relationship and those are prefered to direct manipulation of pivot data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update a row based on a `user_id` the first parameter of the `updateOrCreate` is an array of fields you are looking to match, and the second contains fields that should update. So from what you are saying I believe you should use this:

```
Model::updateOrCreate([
    user_id => 2,
    label_id => 3,
    date => new Carbon('2019-04-04')
],
[
    value => 100
]);
```

Comment: No, I would like to update a specific row targeted by all 3 sections of the composite key - user_id, label_id and date.